# how to align marquee text to left

Tags: html, css

This is my code for `marquee`, but when length of `text` exceeds `div` length than `some starting words are not visible` ,how do i overcome this issue , I tried changing width of `div` element and `marquee` element also but nothing worked  , I also tried to align text to left `align=left` but that too didn't worked, how do i do it ?

```
<div class="video-header" style="margin-left:50px;">
<div class="span8" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px; display:block; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap; color:#353535; overflow:hidden; width:100%;font-size:15px;">
<?php echo ' <marquee LOOP=1 BEHAVIOR=SLIDE>'
   .  stripslashes(_cut($video->title, 280)); ?> - <?php echo time_ago($video->date) . '</marquee>' ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you want a marquee tag?

Comment: @Andrew To scroll video title once , Client's requirement

Comment: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-marquee/ - is that any help?

Comment: @Andrew the code given in above site for marquee not working,they don't even rolling, I tried  in simple html file also , why is that so ? Is any special way to run it? Not working in chome also

Answer (score 0):

Try using  like:

```
 <div>
  <span></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Could you expand on your answer? It's not very useful as it currently stands.